# ¿Por que recibo una referencia nula, de una variable que esta obteniendo un valor?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, null

```
 Private Sub DGARTICULO_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DGARTICULO.DoubleClick
    Dim art, descripcion, ABR As String
    art = DGARTICULO.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(0).Value
    ABR = DGARTICULO.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(1).Value
    descripcion = DGARTICULO.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(2).Value
    Control = "Agregar"

    FrmSolicitudDet.DGDetArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = art
    FrmSolicitudDet.DGDetArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = ABR
    FrmSolicitudDet.DGDetArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = descripcion
    FrmSolicitudDet.DGDetArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value = "0"
    Me.Close()
    'frmDetSoli.ShowDialog()
    'Cod_Articulo = Convert.ToString(DGARTICULO.CurrentRow.Cells[0], Value)
End Sub
```

Obtengo el valor de cada columna y la almaceno en unas variables, para posteriormente enviarlas a otra grid de otro formulario, y me manda una referencia nula, cuando la variable si contiene el valor capturado, no se que pueda ser.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este Otro Código a Prueba de Fallos por Incoerencias en las Variables...
Prueba con este código:

```html
Private Sub DGARTICULO_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DGARTICULO.DoubleClick
' Aquí Activo El Resumen en Siguiente Ante errores
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim art As String, descripcion As String, ABR As String
    art = CStr(DGARTICULO.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(0).Value)
    ABR = CStr(DGARTICULO.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(1).Value)
    descripcion = CStr(DGARTICULO.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(2).Value)
    Control = "Agregar"

    FrmSolicitudDet.DGDetArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = CStr(art)
    FrmSolicitudDet.DGDetArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = CStr(ABR)
    FrmSolicitudDet.DGDetArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = CStr(descripcion)
    ' Aquí Provaria esto 
    'Ya que Puede que te estes saliendo del limite de cells
    FrmSolicitudDet.DGDetArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value = CStr("0")
    Me.Close()
    'frmDetSoli.ShowDialog()
    'Cod_Articulo = Convert.ToString(DGARTICULO.CurrentRow.Cells[0], Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: Bueno te comento, el formulario me funciona bien a si tal cual puse mi codigo, el detalle es cuando a este formulario lo mando a llamar desde otro, es ahi donde quiebra, y me manda una referencia nula, especificamente el error salta aca. FrmSolicitudDet.DGDetArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = art , pero si compruebo, la variable si obtiene el valor

Comment: no creo que se este saliendo del limite de cells porque simplemte estoy asignando valores y la pocision 3 la dejo vacia ya que este valor lo ingreso manual